# Importing file in pandas with read_table() cuts decimal places

Tags: python, pandas

I have a txt file like this (separated by tab):

| Variance | Mean |
| --- | --- |
| 0.001435955236 | -0.001117 |
| 0.002473570225 | 0.003123 |
| 0.002334629124 | -0.003471 |

...and so on.

I load it using pandas.read_table() and the result is a dataframe like this:

|  | Variance | Mean |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.001436 | -0.001117 |
| 1 | 0.002474 | 0.003123 |
| 2 | 0.002335 | -0.003471 |

Why it cuts the decimal places in Variance column? I need those values to be like in the original file.

The file can be found here: https://github.com/jarsonX/Temp_files

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_assets = pd.read_table('assets.txt')

df_assets.head(10)
```

Comment: Instead of linking to an external file, hard-code the first few lines and columns of your file into a StringIO object so that anyone can replicate the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas does not actually "cut" the decimal place, it just rounds when printing. To print with display precision, use

```py
with pd.option_context('display.precision', 10):
    print(df_assets)
```